# How to get back the Object id of the item pushed in an array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to push an object in an array in a Mongodb document.

```
const relative_history = {
        purposeOfVisit: purposeOfVisit,
        currentIssue: currentIssue,
};

await relative_details.history.push(relative_history);
await user_details.save();
```

If i put a constant against `await relative_details.history.push(relative_history);` that constant just shows the number of elements present in the array. How can i get the object id for the object that is pushed?

Comment: Please provide more code context. Where is the user_details and the relative_details comming from?

Answer (score 0):

you can use callback function like:

```js
user_details.save((err, doc)=> {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to save the user_details I assume you have previously done a find operation to get the document based in some query and that the relative_details is a field whithin the user_details, so in the end you could just perform the code below:

```
const relative_history = {
        purposeOfVisit: purposeOfVisit,
        currentIssue: currentIssue,
};

try {

    const user_details = await "YOUR_USER_SCHEMA".findById("YOUR_USER_ID");

    if(!user_details){throw New Error("User not found")}

    user_details.relative_details.history.push(relative_history);
    const updated_user_details = await user_details.save();
    console.log(updated_user_details._id);

} catch(err){// handle errors}
```